# access 2003 application runtime error in access 2010 runtime

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003, runtime-error, ms-access-2010

Hi I have a application designed in access 2003 that has its front-end and back-end split. The front-end has some tables used in the UI and a lot of queries, forms, reports, and macros. This app also has a custom menu bar based on the current state of the application. I am trying to open this app using access 2010 runtime (not the full access 2010) but the application is crashing right off the bat. I get a "Execution of this application has stopped due to a run-time error. The application can't continue and will be shut down." Are there any common problems when running 2003 apps in a 2010 runtime that I could have possibily missed? Also what is the best way to troubleshoot this without using Access 2010 full version (I dont have it).

Thanks :)

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/try/

Comment: Does the app fully compile under A2003? My guess is that there's something wrong that is undetected in A2003 and that A2010 flushes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. I just turned on compact and repair on close. Seemed to have fixed the problem (never was able to figure out wat it was though). The bug was only reproducible on Win7 and not WinXP

Comment: Is there a specific reason for that? The information I have come across always seems to state the exact opposite, including microsofts own online docs related to access.

Comment: If you have split back and and front-end, as you should, compact on close is only suitable fro the front end and irrelevant, because it does not contain data. If there are problems, compact on close without a back-up could make the whole thing impossible to recover. If you have distributed to a user unsplit, and the file is large, it will be very inconvenient to wait so long before closing. If the compact fails, you may not know. If the file is much opened ...

Comment: ... and closed, multiple compact & repair per day is not going to help. Not all Microsoft help is supported by Microsoft users, just think of Track Changes and lookups in tables.